# urllib call seems to block in connectionpool in a very low frequency

Tags: python, urllib3

I use 3rd party API which uses urllib (not sure which version), in some time, the call will be blocked and the last logging from service is "Resetting dropped connection...", which could be found from source code of connectionpool.py in urllib3:

connnectionpool.py

```
    def _get_conn(self, timeout=None):
    """
    Get a connection. Will return a pooled connection if one is available.

    If no connections are available and :prop:`.block` is ``False``, then a
    fresh connection is returned.

    :param timeout:
        Seconds to wait before giving up and raising
        :class:`urllib3.exceptions.EmptyPoolError` if the pool is empty and
        :prop:`.block` is ``True``.
    """
    conn = None
    try:
        conn = self.pool.get(block=self.block, timeout=timeout)

    except AttributeError:  # self.pool is None
        raise ClosedPoolError(self, "Pool is closed.")

    except Empty:
        if self.block:
            raise EmptyPoolError(self,
                                 "Pool reached maximum size and no more "
                                 "connections are allowed.")
        pass  # Oh well, we'll create a new connection then

    # If this is a persistent connection, check if it got disconnected
    if conn and is_connection_dropped(conn):
        log.info("Resetting dropped connection: %s" % self.host)
        conn.close()
        if getattr(conn, 'auto_open', 1) == 0:
            # This is a proxied connection that has been mutated by
            # httplib._tunnel() and cannot be reused (since it would
            # attempt to bypass the proxy)
            conn = None

    return conn or self._new_conn()
```

Then I check conn.close, I guess it may be blocked in close function:

```
    def close(self):
    """
    Close all pooled connections and disable the pool.
    """
    # Disable access to the pool
    old_pool, self.pool = self.pool, None

    try:
        while True:
            conn = old_pool.get(block=False)
            if conn:
                conn.close()

    except Empty:
        pass  # Done.
```

So it seems to mean old_pool doesn't get anything but block here. As old_pool is LifoQueue, and block=False means return if no data get, so it seems no problem here.

However, I met block in some time (even though in a very low frequency), I wonder any possible reason for that cause?

Thanks for your help

===============================

Actually I use [Facebook Ads SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-ads-sdk) to make Facebook API call, which gives the last log message before blocking happened:

```
"logs/aam.log.bk.2015111802:[connectionpool.py:238 - _get_conn Wed, 18 Nov 2015 02:11:21;INFO] Resetting dropped connection: graph.facebook.com"
```

That's why I guess it's related with conn.close in urllib because no other block seems to exist both in Facebook Ads SDK and urllib3 (And another strange thing is that Facebook SDK seems to use requests other than urllib directly, so I don't know why it's related with urllib, please teach me if you know, I just ask one question to FB support team)

From Facebook SDK source code, it should be related with the following code in facebookads/api.py:

```
    # Get request response and encapsulate it in a FacebookResponse
    if method in ('GET', 'DELETE'):
        response = self._session.requests.request(
            method,
            path,
            params=params,
            headers=headers,
            files=files,
        )
    else:
        response = self._session.requests.request(
            method,
            path,
            data=params,
            headers=headers,
            files=files,
        )
    fb_response = FacebookResponse(
        body=response.text,
        headers=response.headers,
        http_status=response.status_code,
        call={
            'method': method,
            'path': path,
            'params': params,
            'headers': headers,
            'files': files,
        },
    )
```

As the origin question described, it happens in a very low frequency, but it happens in different APIs which all make the above call in lower level.

Please tell me if other information needed, thanks for your help~

Comment: Can you share your code of how urllib3 is getting used/called? Snippets from urllib3 code aren't helpful for diagnosing the problem, those are publicly available. :)

Comment: @shazow thanks a lot for help from the author, I add information for call environment, please have a look when you have time :)

Comment: Seems like a problem with how the python-requests session (the _session variable, I assume) is instantiated. That's what determines the pool configuration in urllib3. Also are you running this in a single thread?

Comment: Yes, for the service related with block, it's single thread. I'll check my way of API usage, thanks a lot for your help ~_~